# Is the class component of React JS going to obsolete?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am aware that React’s official documentation states that there's no plan to deprecate class components any time soon. But, according to some website and article, the class components are going to obsolete.

Comment: `according to some website and article` Whici sites and articles claim that? When in doubt, always trust the official documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is no plans](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-i-need-to-rewrite-all-my-class-components) to remove class components. Library developers recommend use functional components in new code.

You can write functional or class components if you can keep code clean and easy to understand for any develop.

Comment: I would remove the opinion part from your answer "And obviously, functional components more easy to read."

Comment: functional component are more easy to read as far as you do not use effects (custom or useEffect). if you starting using them, good luck on easy to read (and easy to write)